# What does this sentence in the song FIGHT SONG - by Rachel Platten mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence, lyrics, songs

The sentence is :

> Like how a single word
>   Can make a heart open

I know the literal meaning , but I don't understand its meaning here?

The link to the video [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo1VInw-SKc)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The interpretation of poetry, song lyrics, and other artistic forms is subjective, and thus ill-suited to our format. There are various other sites devoted to song meanings, though (SongMeanings.com, Lyreka, Songfacts, r/SongMeanings, and so on), and I would advise you to try there. For guidance on what topics are accepted here, please review the [help].

Comment: @choster thank you for the websites... And will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that one word has the capability to hurt you or make you elated. Say your lover in all his/her seriousness says something really hurtful, the expression "heart open" means every word they say impacts you emotionally. "Heart open" implies vulnerability here.